# Display arguments of a newcommand definition in a \cref statement or similar thing

Tags: macros

I am searching for a way to refer to members in a multi-value object (the arguments in a `\newcommand` definition) in a \cref statement, like e.g. here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{myfloat}{H}{flo}%[section]
\floatname{myfloat}{My Float}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{myfloat}{My Float}{My Floats}

\newcommand{\multivaluefloat}[4]{%
  \begin{myfloat}%
    \caption{#2}%
    \label{#1}
    #3

    #4
  \end{myfloat}%
}

\begin{document}

\listof{myfloat}{}

\multivaluefloat{label-a}{This is a caption}{A portion of text.}{Another portion of text.}

In some text we reference \cref{label-a}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
  % Searching for a command referencing 'label-a' to print the equivalent of
  My Float 1 & This is a caption & A portion of text.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must save the third and fourth argument of your `\multivaluefloat` in auxiliary macros. One way would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{myfloat}{H}{flo}%[section]
\floatname{myfloat}{My Float}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{myfloat}{My Float}{My Floats}

\newcommand{\multivaluefloat}[4]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1@first\endcsname{#3}%  <-- added this
  \expandafter\def\csname#1@second\endcsname{#4}% <-- added this
  \begin{myfloat}%
    \caption{#2}%
    \label{#1}
    #3\par
    #4
  \end{myfloat}%
}

% added following line
\newcommand*{\printfloat}[1]{\cref{#1} & \csname#1@first\endcsname & \csname#1@second\endcsname }

\begin{document}

\listof{myfloat}{}

\lipsum[66]

\multivaluefloat{label-a}{This is a caption}{A portion of text.}{Another portion of text.}

In some text we reference \cref{label-a}. \lipsum[66]

\multivaluefloat{another}{This is another caption}{Some stuff here.}{Some stuff there.}

\lipsum[66]

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
  \printfloat{label-a}\\
  \printfloat{another}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, right now `\printfloat` just prints the tabular line as you asked. It is of course possible to have something more flexible to access the pieces separately, but I won't delve into that as I don't know what you are *actually* going to do...

Comment: Wow. Many thanks for this solution! Exactly what I wanted to know.